# Ace-editor.js: How to configure markers behavior, CHANGE_MARKER CHANGE_MARKER_FRONT?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm trying to find where ace-editor.js can be configured to act differently when the matching brackets are highlighted. Here's what it looks like now:
[image]

And I want to be able to configure the color/offset etc.
It seems like ace-editor decides it's color/position based on some config (the CSS class is "br15"), but I couldn't find any config options listed anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

color is controlled by `.ace_bracket` class `.br*` classes are for borders of all markers see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.4/lib/ace/theme/textmate.css#L134-L137
note that there is no way to change color of the bracket itself